# Resize sidebar on content scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to achieve this example for my layout.
https://youtu.be/itV7jvKpWXc

when i scroll content horizontally, my sidebar should change in width for the same amount of horizontal scroll till i reach min-width of sidebar ?

Any easy way to approach it ?

Comment: Where is you code?

Comment: You mean when scroll the page the sidebar will  be smaller?

Comment: Yes, when i scroll horizontaly main-content blocks, sidebar shrinks in width.

Comment: I need you code... attach your html/javascript

Comment: show my answer...hope that will help to you

Answer (score 0):

Add to your `main-content` **onscroll**

```
<div class="main-content" onscroll="resizeSidebar()"></div>
```

In your **javascript** add the function:

```
function resizeSidebar(){
   document.getElementById("sidebar").style.width = "50px";
}
```

you can add to the sidebar **css**:

```
.sidebar {
    transition: 0.5s;  
}
```

It makes the animation for open with slide

Answer (score 0):

this is plus minus what i was trying to achieve, tho it have smull ugly bug when i use horizontal scroll when sidebar reduces in size it makes scrollbar jump also :D

```js
$('.content').scroll(function() {    
    var scrolling = $(".content").scrollLeft();
    console.log(scrolling);
    if (scrolling >= 50) {
      if(!$(".sidebar").hasClass('SmallSidebar')){
         $(".sidebar").addClass("smallSidebar");
        }
    }
    else{
     $(".sidebar").removeClass("smallSidebar");
    }
    if (scrolling >= 50) {
      if(!$(".content").hasClass('smallContent')){
         $(".content").addClass("smallContent");
        }
    }
    else{
     $(".content").removeClass("smallContent");
    }
});

$(function(){
  var curDown = false,
      curYPos = 0,
      curXPos = 0;
  $('.content').mousemove(function(m){
    if(curDown === true){
     $('.content').scrollTop($('.content').scrollTop() + (curYPos - m.pageY)); 
     $('.content').scrollLeft($('.content').scrollLeft() + (curXPos - m.pageX));
    }
  });
  
  $('.content').mousedown(function(m){
    curDown = true;
    curYPos = m.pageY;
    curXPos = m.pageX;
  });
  
  $('.content').mouseup(function(){
    curDown = false;
  });
})

var width = 0;
$('.inner-content').each(function() {
    width += $(this).outerWidth( true );
});
$('.block').css('width', width);
```

```css
body { 
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
div {
 box-sizing: border-box; 
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
.sidebar {
  width: 33.33333%;
  float: left;
  background: blue;
  height: 100vh;
  transition: width 0.2s;
}
.sidebar.smallSidebar {
  width: 80px;
}
.content {
  width: 66.66666%;
  float: left;
  background: #171717;
  height:100%;
  overflow-y:hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  transition: width 0.2s;
  position: relative;
}
.content.smallContent {
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
}
.inner-content {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  transition: width 0.2s;
  position: absolute;
}
.block {
  background: yellow;
    max-width: 320px;
    height: 400px;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
 <div class="content">
 <div class="inner-content">
      <div style="background: #c39eb2;" class="block"></div>
      <div style="background: #a4af93" class="block"></div>
      <div style="background: #0fe7ad;" class="block"></div>
      <div style="background: #f75f31;" class="block"></div>
      <div style="background: #9473c0;" class="block"></div>
      <div style="background: #46087f;" class="block"></div>
      <div style="background: #f59000;" class="block"></div>
      <div style="background: #22e318;" class="block"></div>
      <div style="background: #71454e;" class="block"></div>
      <div style="background: #7eb544;" class="block"></div>
      <div style="background: #2fe218;" class="block"></div>
      <div style="clear: both;"></div>
 </div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```